# Java Class type array

Tags: java, class, return-type

I have this code.This code runs fine. But my intention is to make the return type of the "getLeastPriceItem" method to "Item" instead of double. The "Item" class will be same as it is,there won't be any change in Item class. Just help me out to make the return type as Item instead of double.
Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.*; 
public class ItemDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc1= new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner sc2=new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner sc3=new Scanner(System.in);

        Item[] item= new Item[5];
        for(int i=0;i<item.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter Item Id");
            int itemId=sc1.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter Item name");
            String itemName=sc2.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter Item price");
            double itemPrice=sc3.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter item Discount");
            double itemDiscount=sc3.nextDouble();
            item[i]= new Item(itemId,itemName,itemPrice,itemDiscount);
        }

        double minValue= getLeastPriceItem(item);
        System.out.println("Least item price "+minValue);
    }

    public static double getLeastPriceItem(Item[] item)
    {
        double min;
        min=item[0].getItemPrice();
        for(int i=1;i<item.length;i++)
        {
            if(item[i].getItemPrice()<min)
            {
                min=item[i].getItemPrice();
            }
        }
        return min;
    }
}
    class Item
    {
         private int itemId;
            private String itemName;
            private double itemPrice;
            private double itemDiscount;
            public Item(int itemId, String itemName, double itemPrice,double itemDiscount) {
                this.itemId = itemId;
                this.itemName = itemName;
                this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
                this.itemDiscount = itemDiscount;
        }
            public int getItemId() {
                return itemId;
        }

            public double getItemPrice() {
                return itemPrice;
        }
            public void getItemPrice(double itemPrice) {
                this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
        }
            public double getItemDiscount() {
                return itemDiscount;
        }
            public void setItemDiscount(double itemDiscount) {
                this.itemDiscount = itemDiscount;
        }
            public String getName()
            {
                return itemName;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can keep a track of `minItem` as well with the `min` price and return that `minItem`

```
   public static Item getLeastPriceItem(Item[] item)
    {
        double min;
        Item minItem = item[0];
        min=item[0].getItemPrice();
        for(int i=1;i<item.length;i++)
        {
            if(item[i].getItemPrice()<min)
            {
                min=item[i].getItemPrice();
                minItem = item[i];
            }
        }
        return minItem;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want minimum value item wants to be return, you have to idendify the minimum value item's index. Check below code where variable minIndex is minimum value item's index.

```
public static Item getLeastPriceItem(Item[] item) {
    double min = item[0].getItemPrice();
    int minIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < item.length; i++) {
        if (item[i].getItemPrice() < min) {
            min=item[i].getItemPrice();
            minIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return item[minIndex];
}
```